# HTTP script request "Aborted" status

Tags: javascript, http, httpwebrequest

What might cause a normal external script on my app to show up sometimes 
in Firebug's NET panel as 'Aborted' and not being loaded?

Is this a server issue, or is the browser going nuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in FireBug causing it to echo noise events. Abort is a normal condition for the end of an HttpRequest.

I think that it is going to be fixed in the next release.

Comment: so this is false positive you say? can this happen and requests really might get Aborted?

Comment: @vsync - not a false positive. A true positive, but the abort should be discarded, i.e. not reported, as this is a normal terminal state for an XMLHttpRequest. E.g. to reuse an XMLHttpRequest, as some frameworks do, `.abort()` must be called before reuse. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thank you, this provoked me to disable all scripts on page and enable one-by-one. I've found out that this: http://89.112.11.9/vol/v/vspfiles/templates/sjp/js/common-tab-rotational.js script causes such strange behaviour. But I still can't understand what exactly in this file causes it? I don't see any unusual there!

Comment: perhaps a false alarm but I was just looking for a very similar problem and apparently there is a timeout for Ajax requests that causes the firefox to Abort the request if it takes longer : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?97896-why-my-post-request-get-aborted. I encountered the same explanation about IE.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes, for eg:

On a click event on a hyper-link we try to redirect to another URL through JavaScript/jQuery but the default behavior of a hyper-link click is not blocked using `preventDefault`